# Is there a difference between out-of-domain and out-of-distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, definition, out-of-distribution

When I research papers on the generalisability of ML models, both terms "Out of Distribution" and "Out of Domain" pop up. Are these essentially the same? In my understanding, yes. Although it's hard to tell because when these terms appear in the papers I have read no mathematical definition is provided.
So I guess my question is what is the mathematical definition of "Out of Distribution" and "Out of Domain" and are they equivalent?

Comment: Did you find an answer by yourself so far? I am also interested

Comment: Not really; my research has made me conclude that there are no coherent definitions, and everyone defines it for themselves. Unfortunately, quite a few papers even omit a clear definition. Quite a few also differentiate between far- and near-out of distribution. I figured the latter corresponds with out-of domain and the former with cases where the training data doesn't fully represent the task which is always the case in an open world setting. I have not formalised this yet but would be the next step